# Where can I find sample applications (zentasks, etc) in playframework (2.3.*)?

Tags: playframework

There are two related questions:

1. Looks like in old 'normal' zipped play distribution there was folder with samples. But where can I find them for 2.3.x having installed play with activator?
2. Is there something more than a sample app available in open source?

Best regards, Eugene.

Answer (score 5):

1. Those are now activator templates. You can find them [here](https://typesafe.com/activator/templates). Zentasks is not included there, but you should be able to adapt the 2.2 version to 2.3 easily;
2. You can find a lot of examples in the templates page. There are also examples not related to Play by itself (ex: Akka, plain Java/Scala projects, etc), so you can [filter the Play ones](https://typesafe.com/activator/templates#filter:play) searching for "play".

Comment: 1. Thank you, now it's clear.
2. Well, templates are still not live applications. It would be interesting to see a mature project. And it's strange that there are not so many open source projects using Play as it's been around for seven years already. The only one I was able to find is Guardian's website https://github.com/guardian/frontend